# Solve $ (x^2+y^2)^3=(x^2-y^2)^2$ in rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Everyone talks about Pythagoras equations but here is something similar:

$$ (x^2+y^2)^3=(x^2-y^2)^2$$

This is the shape of a [rose curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium). It does have a peculiar 8-fold intersection at the origin. Two self tangencies at the origin: $y = x$ and $y = -x$.

Wikipedia says this curve is genus 0, meaning there should be a "map" to projective space. We can find a point on the curve e.g. $(x,y)=(0,0)$ or $(1,0)$ and intersect the curve with various lines of rational slope $y=mx+b$ with $m\in \mathbb{Q}$.

There could also be an integer equation by writing the equation in homogenous coordinates $[x:y:z]\in P^1(\mathbb{Q})$.

$$  (x^2+y^2)^3=(x^2-y^2)^2 \, z^2$$

The $z$ coordinate looks extra, but in this part $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

[image]

Comment: The image does not seem to have $(1,0)$ as a point ...?

Comment: You are correct. Can you help me find a nontrivial rational $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The image seems not to be the image of the equations you have since these have $(\pm 1, 0)$ and $(0\pm 1)$ as obvious solutions.

Comment: @cactus314 As others pointed out, your picture was not of the equation in your post.  I replaced it and changed your remark about tangencies, but if you prefer to deal with the curve in your original picture, feel free to rollback and correct the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2)^3= (x^2-y^2)^2$$
Let $x= r \cos (t)$, y = r $\sin(t)$
$$r^6= r^4 (\cos^2(t)-sin^2(t))^2$$
$$r^2= \cos^2(2t)$$
If $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple, then $\cos(t) =\frac{a}{c}$, $\sin(t) =\frac{b}{c}$ should give a rational solution. Because then $r$ is rational, hence $x$ and $y$ are.

Comment: I'm getting $x= \frac{a}{c}  \frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2}$ and $y= \frac{b}{c}  \frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2}$ whenever $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Then $(x,y)$ sure looks rational to me!

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=tu, y=tv$. Then, we have $$t^6\,(u^2+v^2)^3=t^4\,(u^2-v^2)^2,$$ meaning $$u^2+v^2=\frac{(u^2-v^2)^2}{t^2\,(u^2+v^2)^2}=w^2.$$ The solution of this equation in rationals is known:
$$u=w\,\frac{2s}{1+s^2}, v=w\,\frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}, t=\frac{u^2-v^2}{w^3}\tag1$$
So $$(x,y)=\left(t\,u,t\,v\right)$$ with $u,v,t$ from (1) are the non-trivial solutions of the equation: we can reconstruct every rational solution $\neq(0,0)$ from it by letting $u=x$ and $v=y$, then we get $t=1$ because the equation is satisfied.
With $w=1, s=1/2$, we get $$(x,y)=\left(\frac{28}{125}, \frac{21}{125}\right).$$

Comment: The last sentence is not true.

Comment: @cactus314 Better now?

Comment: $u=1$ and $v=0$ leads to $x=1$ and $y=0$.. Which is correct for the equation but not the image.

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thanks for your remark! I hope it's correct, now.

Comment: @cactus314 Your image shows the *rotated* quadrifolium, having another equation: $(x^2+y^2)^3=4\,x^2\,y^2$